# bash command history editing multiple lines

Tags: bash, command-history

Over many years I used `ksh`. I like the possibility to use <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> in command history to call the editor "vi". If this command in the history was spread over many lines - for example because of a while loop - "vi" shows this history also over many lines. With this feature it is easy possible to write complex statements without writing the input to a file.

Years ago I changes to `bash`. It has the same possibility with default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. The slightly difference is that `bash` is merging all lines to one long line delimited with a semicolon. Syntax is still correct but we lose readability.

So what I am doing, I am calling ksh, if I see the commands become complex.

Is there a way to configure `bash` in a way not to merge the lines of the history and act as `ksh` is doing it?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: something like `shopt -u cmdhist` ?

Comment: related on AU, [multiline command chunks in bash history into multiple lines](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133015/283843)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
shopt -s lithist
```

> **lithist**
> If set, and the **cmdhist** option is enabled, multi-line commands are saved to the history  with  embedded  newlines
>         rather than using semicolon separators where possible.

I suspect the reason this isn't enabled by default is because people often use commands like `history | grep something` to find history entry numbers. If a history entry is split across multiple lines, the line that matches `grep` won't always contain the entry number.

Comment: Barner, many thanks. This makes the life much easier. I can get over not to see the complete statement if grepping in the history. Mirabolis, thanks for making a nice posting. But if you do it don't change the content in a way that the context is lost.

Comment: If you want Mirabolis to be notified of your comment, put `@` before his name. The comment about the edit should be below the main question, it's not related to my answer. It looks like all his edits were just formatting, not content, so no context was lost.

Comment: Hi Barmar - thanks for coming back. I wrote originally ctrl-x ctrl-e. Most people will understand this as pressing the ctrl key together with x and then ctrl together with e. Now you can read ctrl-x+ctrl+e. What's that. That's not my posting. I do not understand why people have the constraint to modify others postings. - hans

Comment: @hans Users with < 2000 reputation are allowed to edit questions and answers, but their edits must be reviewed and approved before they're applied. Users with 2000+ reputation can edit without requiring review. You will always be notified if someone edits your posts, so if you think they made a mistake you can correct it. This one seems like a very minor one, most will understand it with the extra `-`, but why haven't you fixed it?

Comment: many thanks for your explanation. You are a great help. In the meantime I fixed the modified posting.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to point out that **bash version 4** does not preserve
multi-line commands when reading history from a timestamp file.

That is you have both

```
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s lithist
```

And save timestamps (so commands have a timestamp separators)
Using a empty string means output from 'history' does nto show the timestamps, but it is active.

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT=''
```

ON shell startup, or using "history -r"  bash will see each of the extra lines of a multi-line command as a separate history entry!   That is on startup, you lose all multi-line history.

This is fixed in bash version 5, though I am not certain of the exact version the 'bug' was fixed.

Comment: similar post, [multiline command chunks in bash history into multiple lines](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133015/283843) and [it's fixed on v5.0.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133015/multiline-command-chunks-in-bash-history-into-multiple-lines#comment2032809_1210371)